# How to preserve multiindex order on join in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Consider The following Example Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'data1':[1,2,3,4]}, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['a','b'],[1,2],], names=['index1','Index2']))


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'data2':[5,6]}, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[1,2]], names=['Index2']))


df3 = df1.join(df2, how='left',sort=False)
```

If I print `df1`, The index is in Order as I expect it:

```
               data1
index1 Index2       
a      1           1
       2           2
b      1           3
       2           4
```

Now I want to add additional data with df2:

```
        data2
Index2       
1           5
2           6
```

but after the merge with `df2`, the Order of the Index has changed. Index2 is now the first level. I explicitly tried to forbid it with using `sort=False`, but it still promotes the joined index to the first level:

```
print(df3)

               data1  data2
Index2 index1              
1      a           1      5
       b           3      5
2      a           2      6
       b           4      6
```

The pandas documentation states, that `how='left'` does accomplish that, but it does not seem to work.

Is there a way i can enforce the resulting index_columns of the merge to be in the same order as df1? Like this:

```
               data1  data2
Index1 index2              
a     1           1      5
b      1           3      5
a      2           2      6
b      2           4      6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`swaplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) and [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df3 = df1.join(df2, how='left').swaplevel().reindex(df1.index)
```

Or [`reorder_levels`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reorder_levels.html):

```
df3 = df1.join(df2, how='left').reorder_levels(df1.index.names).reindex(df1.index)
```

Output:

```
               data1  data2
index1 Index2              
a      1           1      5
       2           2      6
b      1           3      5
       2           4      6
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess it uses `np.unique` to set the index:

```
>>> np.unique(df1.index.names + df2.index.names)
array(['Index2', 'index1'], dtype='<U6')
```

So you have to handle it manually:

```
idx, order = np.unique(df1.index.names + df2.index.names, return_index=True)
df3 = df3.reorder_levels(idx[np.argsort(order)]).sort_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> df3
               data1  data2
index1 Index2              
a      1           1      5
       2           2      6
b      1           3      5
       2           4      6
```